# How to set one rule for multiple input in Vue Element?

Tags: vue.js

I am doing [form validation](https://element.eleme.io/2.4/#/en-US/component/form#validation). I want to make simple rule that do check if field are completed. But I can't understand how to accept one rule for multiple input fields.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/b9q3gx8n/1/

```
<el-form :model="ruleForm" :inline="true" :rules="rules" ref="ruleForm" >
    <el-form-item label="№" prop="mycheck">
        <el-input v-model="ruleForm.xxx"></el-input>
        {{ruleForm.petition_number}}
    </el-form-item>

    <el-form-item label="№" prop="mycheck">
        <el-input v-model="ruleForm.yyy" border>Ходатайство ДСП</el-input>
        {{ruleForm.DSP_attribute}}
    </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

My rule for checking:

```
 rules: {
    mycheck: [
      { required: true, message: 'Please input required', trigger: 'blur' },
      { min: 1, trigger: 'blur' }

    ],
}
```